# How to count page in one sheet of excel use Uipath? Can give me some idea?

Tags: automation, rpa, uipath

I use Uipath and I want to check number page of excel sheet, if it larger 5 will output error. But not have activities can check it. Does somebody have the idea for it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because concept has nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to count the number of sheets in an excel sheet,here is the method using UiPath.

Read the excel using Excel application scope
store the output of the excel application scope with a variable (ex:wb)
convert the variable to an array (newvariable=wb.Getsheets().ToArray)
Get the length of the array (newvariable.length)
This would give you the number of sheets in the excel workbook.

Regards,
Swapnil